# Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

Liouville's theorem states that each holomorphic function from the closed complex plane into itself is constant. How can this theorem be applied to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: You need to ask precise questions. It's impossible to look at that image and see what's troubling you/what needs explanation without your help. (In addition, you'll get a more favorable response if you keep the post self-contained and copy over the relevant portion of the text instead of posting an image.)

Comment: Thanks for these guidelines. I'll follow them while asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that Louville's Theorem can be used to provide a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Suppose there exists a polynomial $P(z)$ of degree at least $1$ with no complex roots. Then $f(z) = 1/P(z)$ is holomorphic on the entire complex plane (entire). Once you show that $\vert P(z) \vert$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{C}$, you can conclude that $\vert 1/P(z) \vert$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$. But since $1/P(z)$ is entire, by Louiville's Theorem, it must be constant. However, this implies that $P(z)$ is constant, which is a contradiction since we assumed $P(z)$ has degree at least $1$. Therefore $P(z)$ has at least one root.

Comment: Right, P(z) has atleast one root. Just correct me if I'm wrong.
Do we need to use induction to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra. Like, P(z) can be expressed as (z-z1)*q(z) where q(z) is a polynomial of degree (n-1) and then repeat the same procedure?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra is actually just the statement that a polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one root. If you want to show that a polynomial with complex coefficients of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ complex roots, then yes, induction is the way to go and you proceed exactly as you described.

Also, if you want to be totally thorough, you have to prove that if $z_1$ is a root of $P(z)$, then you can express $P(z)$ as $(z - z_1)q(z)$ where $q(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n - 1$. This can also be done by induction.

Comment: Got it, thanks.